# Error in pandas multiprocessing code - dataframe is not callable

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I'm trying to optimise a distance calculation over a large file using multiprocessing. I've designed the below code, but can anyone explain why it throws the error ['DataFrame' object is not callable]?

It appears to be something to do with "map" inside parallelize_dataframe, possibly caused by how I've designed test_func, but not sure how to resolve. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

nearest_calc3 = None
nearest_calc3 = postcodes.head(1000).copy() # Test top 1000

partitions = 5
cores = mp.cpu_count()

def parallelize_dataframe(data, func):
    data_split = np.array_split(data, partitions)
    pool = mp.Pool(cores)
    data = pd.concat(pool.map(func, data_split)) # <-- Problem here?
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return data

def nearest(inlat1, inlon1, inlat2, inlon2, store, postcode):
    lat1 = np.radians(inlat1)
    lat2 = np.radians(inlat2)
    longdif = np.radians(inlon2 - inlon1)
    r = 6371.1009 # gives d in kilometers
    d = np.arccos(np.sin(lat1)*np.sin(lat2) + np.cos(lat1)*np.cos(lat2) * np.cos(longdif)) * r
    near = pd.DataFrame({'store': store, 'postcode': postcode, 'distance': d})
    near_min = near.loc[near['distance'].idxmin()]
    x = str(near_min['store']) + '~' + str(near_min['postcode']) + '~' + str(near_min['distance'])
    return x

def test_func(data, stores): # <-- Or maybe here?
    data['appended'] = data['lat'].apply(nearest, args=(data['long'], stores['lat'], stores['long'], stores['index'], stores['pcds']))
    data[['store','store_postcode','distance_km']] = data['appended'].str.split("~",expand=True)
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = parallelize_dataframe(nearest_calc3, test_func(nearest_calc3, stores))
```

And the full error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RemoteTraceback                           Traceback (most recent call last)
RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-501c0f76106a> in <module>
     32 #x = test_func(nearest_calc3, stores)
     33 
---> 34 test = parallelize_dataframe(nearest_calc3, test_func(nearest_calc3, stores))

<ipython-input-21-501c0f76106a> in parallelize_dataframe(data, func)
      9     data_split = np.array_split(data, partitions)
     10     pool = mp.Pool(cores)
---> 11     data = pd.concat(pool.map(func, data_split))
     12     pool.close()
     13     pool.join()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    266         in a list that is returned.
    267         '''
--> 268         return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
    269 
    270     def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    655             return self._value
    656         else:
--> 657             raise self._value
    658 
    659     def _set(self, i, obj):

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Comment: Post the complete error message starting from `Traceback`

Comment: Added into the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the last line:

```
test = parallelize_dataframe(nearest_calc3, test_func(nearest_calc3, stores))
```

`test_func(...)` will return a dataframe and you pass that into `parallelize_dataframe`.
But this function is expecting a callable.

You want something like this:

```
test = parallelize_dataframe(nearest_calc3, test_func)
```

As you want to always pass `stores` into `test_func` in addition to `nearest_calc3`, you could use `partial` to do so:

```
test_func_with_stores = functools.partial(test_func, stores)
```

`test_func_with_stores` is then a callable that takes a single parameter.
Unfortunately `partial` *fills* the parameters from left to right, so you would have to change `test_func` so that `stores` is the first parameter.

Comment: Right, got it. Just struggling with where/how to pass in "stores" now.

Comment: You can use `functools.partial` for that. Let me extend my answer.

Comment: Thanks. The partial function solved the original issue although an error now claims the "nearest" function I'm tyring to apply inside test_func is not defined. Does a partial function lose the ability to call functions from within them?

Comment: That’s not due to the partial, but because of the parallelisation. Every function is basically executed in a clean interpreter and can only access what is given as argument. You can simply move the definition of nearest into test_func

Comment: My days! That fixed the definition problem (interestingly I had to reimport pandas and numpy inside the function too - which makes sense given your explanation), but it's now complaining it [cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'> with these indexers [nan] of <class 'float'>]. The only floats are the co-ordinates, so unsure what this means.

Comment: I think it would be better to create a new question if you need further help with the pandas stuff.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208177/discussion-between-b-winter-and-m-spiller).